# Real-time progress of queued jobs laravel at the front end

Tags: laravel, sockets, real-time, laravel-5.8, php-socket

I am working on Laravel 5.8, and I have a button that starts queue jobs in the database, sending thousands of emails immediately.

I want to monitor the progress of the queue on the front-end using a status or progress bar in real-time. I am considering using **Pusher**, **WebSocket**, or **Laravel Echo**, but I am confused about which solution to choose because it involves the database table as well.